# How can I Draw rectangle in programmatically

Tags: python, math, diagram, projection

How can I draw rectangle(Oblique projection view) in programmatically(python) by giving height, width and depth.

Comment: You should generally show what you've researched and where you're stuck in code, with a concrete problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Python's `turtle` module, [here is the v3.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html). On top of height, width and depth, you will need to think about an angle for the projection - I think this is typically 30/45 degrees.

To get you started... [adapting code by Y. Daniel Liang](http://www.cs.armstrong.edu/liang/py/html/UsefulTurtleFunctions.html).

```
import turtle

w = 100
h = 50
d = 20
angle = 30

def drawRectangle(width, height): 
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(height)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(width)

turtle.penup() 
turtle.goto(0, 0)
turtle.pendown()
drawRectangle(w, h)
turtle.left(angle)
turtle.forward(d)
turtle.right(angle)
drawRectangle(w, h)
```

Comment: Tnaks kappers, but I think its not possible to draw a rectangle in Oblique projection view, I need to draw rectangle dynamically with in Oblique projection view :(

Comment: @paradox Your question needs a bit of clarification, as I think the code snippet above demonstrates it is definitely possible with a bit of work...